# Socket Recv function with Thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, condition-variable

Hello i have produced a communication protocol software and i came across one issue. Issue is that when i use thread for recv function my buffer that get from socket is missing. I try to use condition_variable and mutex but response is always same. I thought that program go to next line before recv function finished.Because when i use Sleep(2000) after send function, program is running correctly.
When recv buffer is bigger than 1024 bytes, my program is failed.

Firs value of parameter

```
bool ok=true
int hıdıdı_hıdıdı=0;
```

class ıvır_zıvır

```
class ıvır_zıvır {
public:
    std::mutex mutex;
    std::condition_variable cv;
};
```

Function Recv_data

```
void connect_tcp::Recv_data(SOCKET s,mms_response &response,Signals *signals,bool &ok,ıvır_zıvır &ıvır) {
   LinkedList** list = new LinkedList * [1000];
   uint8_t* buffer = new uint8_t [10000];
   ok = false;
   unique_lock<mutex>lck(ıvır.mutex);
   recv(s, (char*)buffer, 10000, 0);
   ıvır.cv.wait(lck, [] {return hıdıdı_hıdıdı == 1; });
   decode_bytes(response,buffer, list,signals);
}
```

Function send_data

```
int connect_tcp::send_data(SOCKET s, mms_response &response,LinkedList** list,int &j,bool &ok, ıvır_zıvır& ıvır) {
    this_thread::sleep_for(0.3s);
    int i = 0;
    int k = 0;
    uint8_t* buffer = new uint8_t[10000];
    while (i<j)
    {
        for (auto it = list[i]->data.begin(); it != list[i]->data.end(); it++)
        {
            buffer[k]=*it;
            k++;

        }
        i++;

    }
    while (ok==true)
    {
        this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    }
    int jk = 0;
    {
        jk= send(s, (const char*)buffer, list[0]->size, 0);
        cout << jk << " Bytes sent" << endl;
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1)); 
    }
    hıdıdı_hıdıdı = 1;
    ıvır.cv.notify_all();
    this_thread::sleep_for(2s);
    hıdıdı_hıdıdı = 0;
    ok = true;
    if (jk == -1) {
        exit(-1);
    }
    i = 0;
    while (i<j) {
        delete list[i]; 
        i++;
    }
    j = 1;
    return jk;
}
```

Function that call Recv_data and send_data

```
void cotp_connection(Cotp_connection cotp, connect_tcp* connection, mms_response response, LinkedList** list, SOCKET s) {
    int i = 1;
    cotp.Begin_Transport_Protocol(list, i);
    cotp.Header_file(list, i);
    thread t2(&connect_tcp::Recv_data, connection, s, ref(response), nullptr, ref(tt), ref(ıvır));
     connection->send_data( s, response, list, ref(i), ref(tt),ıvır);
     t2.join();
}
```

connect_tcp class

```
class connect_tcp
{
public:

    SOCKET ConnectWithTcp();
    int send_data(SOCKET s,mms_response &response, LinkedList** list,int &j,bool &ok,ıvır_zıvır &ıvır);
    connect_tcp();
    connect_tcp(char* ip, int set_port);
    void Close_tcp(SOCKET s);
    void Recv_data(SOCKET s, mms_response& response, Signals* signals, bool& ok, ıvır_zıvır& ıvır);
    boolean s;

private:
    SOCKET server;
    SOCKADDR_IN addr;
    int port;
    WSADATA WSAData;
};
```

Threading output

```
CBFPPIOC4$ST$Mod$stVal
CBFPPIOC4$ST$Mod$t
CBFPPIOC4$ST$Op
CBFPPIOC4$ST$Op$general
CBFPPIOC4$ST$Op$═
```

Correct output

```
CBFPPIOC4$ST$Mod$stVal
CBFPPIOC4$ST$Mod$t
CBFPPIOC4$ST$Op
CBFPPIOC4$ST$Op$general
CBFPPIOC4$ST$Op$q
CBFPPIOC4$ST$Op$t
CBFPPIOC4$ST$Str
CBFPPIOC4$ST$Str$dirGeneral
CBFPPIOC4$ST$Str$general
CBFPPIOC4$ST$Str$q
CBFPPIOC4$ST$Str$t
```

These outputs' buffer is bigger than 1024 bytes. If wonder about classes,please write comment.i will edit my post for add classes.

Comment: Why does `cotp_connection` spawn a thread and immediately `.join` on it? That makes no sense.

Comment: i thouht if you dont make thread `.join`, function does not work. When function work ? When make thread `.join` or when thread call function ? @Botje

Comment: The point of a thread is to do work elsewhere so this thread can continue. Calling `.join` effectively blocks the thread until the other thread is finished, so all that accomplishes here is you're calling `Recv_data` in a very expensive manner.

Comment: Can you explain in English what each thread is supposed to do and what resources they are supposed to share?

Comment: I use thread because when send function that inside of send_data function block finished, recv_data function get all of response buffer and decode it , while this is happening i want to block send_data function blocked until the decode end. Because of this i use condition_variable.But recv function inside of recv_data function block cannot get all of buffer and go to next line before gets all.

Comment: So why can't you call `send_data` and inside it call `recv_data` after the `send` call?

Comment: Because i thought recv_data run when make it ‘.join’

Comment: i will try your opinion and give you feed back, thanks

Comment: Actually i want to create a handler that when came data from socket my recv_data function recognize that and decode it. Is that possible with thread or are there any another method more effectively @Botje

Comment: Of course it is possible using threads. Your main problem is _framing_: your receiver needs to know when it has received all the data. Common approaches are to send the length before the payload, or use the structure of data such that `decode_bytes` can see when there is logically no more data. (eg in JSON all structural { and } must be balanced, as must all [ and ])

Comment: Ok thank you , i have one more question about thread. When  does  recv_data function run ? At function called or make thread .join ?

Comment: The thread starts running the moment you call the `thread` constructor. `join` simply waits for it to end.

Comment: Okey thank you , i rode a lo of writing about thread but i could not understand this , thanks to you i understood thank you a lot